# Javascript context confusion

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var test = {
 setup: function() { property = 'hello!'; console.log(this); }
};
```

When I run `test.setup();` and print out `test.property();` it gives me `undefined`. I understand it's because I need to do `this.property` but my question is: why?

I can clearly see that the context is the `test` object via `console.log(this)`, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Also property is not a method so that should be an error.

Comment: `property` is not part of the test object. It's part of the function you assigned to `setup` variable, which if unbound, will default to window.property which is a global.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work that way - `this` is *never* implicit.

Comment: @Pointy Ok, but doing var test = {hello : 'hi!'} doesn't have this but it works in this case. Is this just an exception?

Comment: That's a completely different situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When JavaScript finds a loose assignment like `property = 'hello!'`, it will create a global variable (or raise an error, if in strict mode). So if you want it to be a property, you have to be explicit.

Comment: Ok, but doing var test = {hello : 'hi!'} doesn't have this but it works in this case. Is this just an exception?

Comment: @0xSina that example, `var test = {hello: 'hi!'}`, is quite different than the code in your original question, and simply assigns to a variable an object reference constructed from an object literal expression. Your original question involved a variable name ("property") inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this situation, `property = 'hello!'` is the same as `window.property = 'hello!'`, not `this.property = 'hello!'`.

If you assign to an *undeclared* variable, it will create a global variable.

Comment: Ok, but doing var test = {hello : 'hi!'} doesn't have this but it works in this case. Is this just an exception?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variable with "no var" you will "accidentally" create global variable (attached to window object) so rule of thumb: Always use "var" with variable declaration.
With "var" here, you will create local variable to setup function.